# Simple Mongoid associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm just starting with Mongodb using Mongoid in Rails and I'm wondering how to create the simple associations between these three models:

**User** which has many **Photos** which has many **Tags** which has many **Photos**…

I don't want to embed any of the models since I want to be able to present a list of for instance all Photos or all Tags in certain views…

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Mongoid Docs on Associations](http://mongoid.org/docs/associations/). Look under "RELATIONAL ASSOCIATIONS"

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document 
  references_many :photos
end

class Photos
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :user
end
```

Comment: I'm having no problem with the User > Photos association. But how about the Photos <> Tags one where a tag can belong to many Photos?

Comment: Ok! Think I solved it using references_and_referenced_in_many on both Photos and Tags… correct?